# pipe, { list; } only works with some programs

Tags: shell, pipe

Need explanations from power users for such unpredictable behaviour:

```
ps -eF | { head -n 1;grep worker; }
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       441     2  0     0     0   2 paź15 ?       00:00:00 [kworker/2:1H]
```

everything looks ok whereas

```
ls -la / | { head -n 1;grep sbin; }
```

displays only output from `head`

...
I thought about `stdout 2>&1` and doesn't work neither
for me it's weird, any explanations or suggest how to handle it?

Comment: The last one should print out everything. The `head` and `grep` do nothing there.

Comment: yes, You are right. But instead of it, why ps -eF works while ls -la / not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some investigating using `strace` and it appears to be due to the way the program on the left side of the pipeline does it's writing to the terminal. When the `ls` command is executed it writes all of the data in a single `write()`. This causes `head` to consume all of stdin.

On the other hand `ps` writes out data in batches, so only the first `write()` is consumed by `head`, and then it exists. Later calls to `write()` will go to the newly spawned `grep` process.

This means that it would not work if the process you are trying to `grep` for did not occur in the first `write()`, since `grep` does not get to see all of the data (it sees even less than just the data minus the first line).

Here is an example of trying to grep for pid 1 on my system:

```
$ ps -eF | { head -n2; }
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0  1697  3768   2 Oct03 ?        00:00:03 /lib/systemd/systemd
$ ps -eF | grep '/lib/systemd/systemd$'
root         1     0  0  1697  3768   2 Oct03 ?        00:00:03 /lib/systemd/systemd
$ ps -eF | { head -n1; grep '/lib/systemd/systemd$'; }
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

Your `ps -eF` example only works by chance.

Comment: great and comprehensive expalnation thanks a lot

Comment: Actually it's more of a race condition. It's just that it's slower performing multiple `write()` calls. If the `head` were slow to perform it's `read()` call (such that the pipe buffer had all the data in it), it would exhibit the same behavior across both `ls` and `ps`.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by buffering in glibc. In the case of `ls` the output is in one internal buffer and as such is passed just to `head`. For the `ps -eF`, the output is bigger and so once `head` finishes, the following `grep` gets the remaining parts of (but not the whole) output of `ps`.

You can get rid of it by un-buffering the pipe - for example with `sed -u` (I'm not sure it isn't a GNU extension):

```
$ ls -al / | sed -u "#" | { head -n 1; grep bin; }
total 76
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  2 21:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  8192 Oct  3 01:54 sbin
```

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that `head -n 1` reads more than 1 line. For optimal throughput, head reads chunks of bytes, so it might read 1024 bytes at a time, and then look through those bytes for the first line break. Since the line break might occur in the middle of that 1024 bytes, the rest of the data is lost. It can't be put back on the pipe. So the next process that executes only gets bytes 1025 and on.

Your first command happens to succeed because the `kworker` process is after that first chunk that `head` reads.

In order for this to work, `head` would have to read 1 character at a time. But this is extremely slow, so it doesn't.
The only way to do something like this efficiently is to have a single process do both the "head" and "grep".

Here are 2 ways of doing this:

```
echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' | perl -ne 'print if $i++ == 0 || /4/'
```

or

```
echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4\n5' | awk '{if (NR == 1 || /4/) print }'
```

There are a lot more...

Comment: yes I have known 'way of awk' to handle this task, but was wondering why behaviour was so unpredictable with { list; }. Thanks for clarify how it works.  I'm impressed with all above answers

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the first line or two, the following type of trick
works and avoids the buffering problems caused by using two different
commands to read the output stream:

```
$ ps -eF   | { IFS= read -r x ; echo "$x" ; grep worker; }
$ ls -la / | { IFS= read -r x ; echo "$x" ; grep sbin; }
```

The `read` is built-in to the shell and doesn't consume an entire buffer
of input just to output the one line, so using `read` leaves all the
rest of the output for the following command.

If you want to accentuate the buffering problems shown by your examples
that use two different commands, add a `sleep` to them to eliminate
the timing issues and allow the command on the left to generate all its
output before the commands on the right try to read any of it:

```
$ ps -eF   | { sleep 5 ; head -n 1 ; grep worker; }
$ ls -la / | { sleep 5 ; head -n 1 ; grep sbin; }
```

Now, both the above examples fail in the same way -- the `head` reads
an entire buffer of the output just to produce the one line, and that
buffer is not available to the following `grep`.

You can see the buffering problem even more clearly by using some examples
that number the output lines so you can tell which lines are missing:

```
$ ps -eF          | cat -n | { sleep 5 ; head -n 1 ; head ; }
$ ls -la /usr/bin | cat -n | { sleep 5 ; head -n 1 ; head ; }
```

A simple way to see the buffering problem is to use `seq` that generates
a list of numbers.  We can easily tell which numbers go missing:

```
$ seq 1 100000    | { sleep 5 ; head -n 1 ; head ; }
1

1861
1862
1863
1864
1865
1866
1867
1868
1869
```

My trick solution using the shell to read and echo the first line works
correctly even with the sleep delay added:

```
$ seq 1 100000 | { sleep 5 ; IFS= read -r x ; echo "$x" ; head ; }
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Below is a full example showing the `head` buffering issues, showing how
`head` consumes an entire buffer of the output just to produce its five
lines each time.  That consumed buffer is not available to the next
`head` command in the sequence:

```
$ seq 1 100000 | { sleep 5 ; head -5 ; head -5 ; head -5 ; head -5 ; }
1
2
3
4
5

1861
1862
1863
1864
499
3500
3501
3502
3503
7
5138
5139
5140
5141
```

Looking at the number `1861` above, we can calculate the size of the
buffer being used by `head` by counting the `seq` output from `1` to
`1860`:

```
$ seq 1 1860 | wc -c
8193
```

We see that `head` is buffering by reading a full 8KB (8*1024 bytes)
of the pipe output at a time, even to produce just a few lines of its
own output.